# How to insert current time (hh:mm) in org mode without date

Tags: org-mode

How can I insert the current time (format hh:mm) in org-mode without a date, i.e. just the time?

Comment: How about using something like this snippet?:   `(insert (format-time-string "%I:%M" (current-time)))`   Is there anything specific relating to your use-case that requires an `org-mode` solution?

Comment: There is no specific Org mode function to do that, because such an object does not mean anything to Org mode: you can use a generic function as @lawlist indicates, or you can enter it by hand (it is just text after all). The point is that once inserted, Org mode is not going to do anything special with it: in particular it is not an Org mode timestamp.

Comment: @NickD; Yes you are right its not org specific and indeed @lawlist solved the problem (I wrapped it in a `yasnipped` though). Thanks!

Comment: @lawlist Thanks. This is what I needed. I created a function and added to my `.emacs` file `(defun ddate () (interactive) (insert (format-time-string "%I:%M" (current-time))))` and I call it with `M-x dd <TAB>` This is OK, right? In terms of key bindings etc.

Comment: @zeynel -- your interactive function looks fine.  In terms of using tab completion to assist in locating an interactive function with `M-x`, that sounds fine too.